# How to detect calloc/malloc of objects with constructors - c++

Tags: visual-c++, constructor, new-operator, code-analysis, calloc

We have a large application of legacy C code largely renamed to .cpp instead .c. This old code makes uses of various structures allocated with calloc from the old C days. Some of structures have had constructors added or now include classes with constructors.

Hopefully we'll find all uses of calloc and convert those to 'new' however some invariably slip through the net. Are there are compiler warnings (we use Visual Studio) or static analysis tools that can pick up on these problems at compile time? e.g.

```
struct A
{
    std::vector<int>     needsToBeConstructed;
    int otherStuff;
}
...

A* problem = (A)calloc(sizeof(A)); // be nice to get a warning
A* correct = new A(); // should be ok
```

I've done a google & MSDN search and can't find anything obvious.

Comment: Can't you try to find them all with regex? And replace them?

Comment: We have a few hundred other structures which we do want to continue to use calloc for. We also don't know which objects do use variables with constructors and which don't - especially when objects are in objects etc.